# Facebook API: Getting list of profiles ordered by relevance

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I get a list of profiles via Facebook Graph API or FQL ordered by their relevance to the current user just as the result I would get after a name search within Facebook?

A graph API search like `/search?type=user&fields=name&q=NAME` with my current access token returns an irrelevant list of `NAME`s while a search within Facebook for `NAME` returns most probable matches for me, starting from friends, friends of friends with most mutual friends, etc.

With and FQL query like

> SELECT uid, name FROM user
>   WHERE strpos(name, 'NAME') >=0
>   AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
>   ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC

I can search within my friends and get the results ordered by mutual friend count. But I want to have non-friends in the result list as well.

How can I implement a Graph or FQL search query to get a similar set of profiles ordered by relevance to the current user making the query?